# ¿Cómo se dice "bootstrap" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática, inglés

En el mundo de la informática se utiliza mucho el término bootstrap (últimamente para referirse a Twitter bootstrap).

Veo que la traducción más directa es la de "lengüeta de zapatos", es decir, la tira (generalmente de cuero) que se sitúa en la parte posterior de un zapato y que, tirando de ella, se ayuda a situar el pie dentro del calzado. Se deduce de ello cierto sentido de "herramienta autosuficiente".

Pero claro, esto no encaja demasiado con el significado que puede tener un bootstrap informático, que yo entendería como "conjunto de herramientas para conseguir un producto autosuficiente".

La pregunta es, entonces: ¿existe alguna palabra (o conjunto de ellas) que encaje con esta definición? En tal caso, ¿es conveniente utilizarla en detrimento del anglicismo *bootstrap*?

Comment: Un poquito relacionado: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Bootstrap

Comment: The original meaning of *bootstrap* comes from a set phrase, *pull yourself up by your bootstraps*, which means (approximately): use leverage to pull yourself up; but, ironically, leverage yourself *against yourself* -- which is patently impossible.  Anyway, in a computer context, what this word conveys to me in English: you start with nothing, and a bootstrap process enables you to get things going, starting from zero.  Kind of like on a 10-speed bicycle, if you need to start on an incline going up, you have to start in first gear, and then work your way up the gears. (Ignore that if it...

Comment: ... was already obvious.)

Comment: En [estadística](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics) su significado real no tiene nada que ver con el significado literal, así que la traducción solo complicaría las cosas. No se traduce.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Creo que esta es una de esas palabras que, al intentar traducirlas, crean más confusión de que la resuelven. Lo que yo haría es escribirla en inglés, en cursiva.

"Bootstrap" como proceso de encendido de un sistema operativo, normalmente se abrevia "boot", y esto se puede traducir, sin problemas de comprensión, con "arranque" o "inicio". "Reboot" sería "reinicio" ("rearranque" suena un poco raro).

Pero "bootstrap" en el sentido más genérico de conjunto de herramientas y procedimientos para que un entorno se construya a sí mismo, no creo que tenga una traducción clara.

Y si te refieres a ["Twitter Bootstrap"](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter_Bootstrap), es un producto comercial, así que no creo que deba intentar traducirse. ¡Sería como llamar a este sitio "Intercambio de Pilas"!

Comment: Esto es lo correcto. Inventarse una traducción sólo creará confusión, al ser un término ya conocido y usado.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, hay cosas como estas que no se deberian traducir.

Comment: A dato informativo, el concepto de "arranque" está relacionado con el nombre del producto: Twitter Bootstrap provee de muchas herramientas que permiten fácilmente "arrancar" un proyecto web, teniendo ya resueltos aspectos comunes a muchos ellos.

Comment: Discrepo humildemente. Inventarse traducciones es lo que alguien hizo la primera vez de todo aquello que se traduce. Otra cosa es que en determinados idiomas como el español prefiramos (sobre todo en el campo de la tecnología) aceptar el término extranjero en lugar de acuñar uno nuevo, que tiende a parecernos "raro". Supongo que depende de la idiosincrasia de cada país, pero no me imagino a un francés no-inventando una palabra francesa equivalente a cualquier neologismo. Y en este caso particular, creo que "Secuencia de arranque" es bastante aceptable.

Answer (score 13):

La imagen/metáfora original es "levantarse uno mismo del suelo tirando de las lengüetas de los zapatos". Dependiendo del contexto (y de los gustos personales) se puede traducir por "arranque" o conservar la expresión en inglés.

Answer (score 7):

*Arranque autosuficiente* o para abreviar *autoarranque*. Es el término más conciso que se ajusta con la definición.

En entornos tecnológicos se presupone el conocimiento del término inglés, pero si se quiere ser estricto siempre es mejor no utilizar anglicismo. La conveniencia o no de la utilización la decide el hablante.

Comment: El problema es que si lo traduces por "autoarranque", el que sepa lo que es un "bootstrap" no lo va a entender, y el que no lo sepa, pues tampoco, con el agravante de que si lo busca en Google no va a encontrar nada demasiado relevante. Y cuando luego, en otra publicación, encuentre el mismo término traducido de otra manera, no asociará que están hablando de la misma cosa.

Answer (score 7):

**Secuencia de arranque** o **Secuencia de inicio**. No es *inventado*, es lo que ponía en los libros de informática de cuando yo era joven, de lo cual hace lamentablemente bastante tiempo. Creo que es una traducción acertada, precisa y que aguanta bien el paso del tiempo, y no parece *raruna* como suele pasar en otros casos.

Comment: Secuencia de arranque sería el procedimiento realizado por el bootstrap/cargador. Está bien recordar los libros de la carrera.

Answer (score 5):

"Bootstrap" tiene, por lo menos, tres significados en inglés.

1. Obviamente, el primero es una **correa de bota** ("boot strap"), y refiere a un [parte de una bota](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping#Etymology):

[image]

2. De este significado literal, es el modismo básico que habla del proceso de inicio de un proceso autosostenido que se supone debe proceder sin entrada externa. [cita (inglés)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping#Etymology)
3. Del modismo básico hay variaciones específicas para algunas aplicaciones, incluso [negocios](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(negocios)) e [informática](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

Según las citaciones de Wikipedia arriba mencionadas, puedes ver que en todos contextos, menos el literal, la traducción de "bootstrap" o "bootstrapping" a español es "bootstrap" o "bootstrapping" respectivamente.

Answer (score 3):

Siendo yo mismo un profesional informático, **Bootstrap** no se traduce. Es el nombre propio de la herramienta y no necesita traducción, de la misma forma que *Chrome* no se traduce a *Cromo*, *Firefox* a *Zorro de fuego*, *Facebook* a *Caralibro*, *Windows* a *Ventanas*, o el acrónimo *CSS* por *HEC* (*Hoja de Estilo en Cascada*), etc.

Usar cualquier tipo de traducción, por más acertada que sea, sólo puede generar confusión al querer comunicarse con un desarrollador de habla hispana.

Comment: Bootstrap no es una herramienta, es una rutina de carga, que hoy en día se encuentra en la BIOS.

Answer (score 3):

Muy nuevo no es el término **bootstrap**, los ordenadores de los años 60/70 disponían de un **cargador**. Los cargadores más primitivos que llegué a conocer no eran sino una rutina que estaba en la memoria del ordenador y cuyas primeras instrucciones hacían que el ordenador leyera desde un dispositivo de entrada el resto de la rutina que iniciaba la carga del sistema operativo. Esas primeras instrucciones de metían desde la consola, estableciendo como dirección siguiente a ejecutar la dirección en memoria donde residía el cargador, y lanzando su ejecución. Y la consola no era una pantalla, era un panel lleno de luces, pulsadores y diales. Todo muy cómodo.

Y sí, el término 'bootstrap' significa 'calzador' (en un diccionario escolar). Se atribuye su origen a una de las historias del Baron Munchausen, que se jactaba de haberse salvado de su caída en un pantano tirando de los calzadores de sus botas, para llevarse a sí mismo a tierra firme.

Answer (score 3):

Permítanme que, después de 6 años de hecha la pregunta, añada algo aún no comentado, apartándonos de la informática.

En matemáticas, en concreto en probabilidad y estadística, está bien establecida la traducción de *bootstrap method* o *bootstrapping* como *método autodocimante*.

De [docimasia](https://dle.rae.es/docimasia),

> Del gr. δοκιμασία dokimasía 'prueba, ensayo'. [DRAE]

[Este es el primer artículo](https://www.investigacionyciencia.es/revistas/investigacion-y-ciencia/mejora-porcina-125/mtodos-estadsticos-intensivos-por-ordenador-5775) en el que tuve la oportunidad de conocer el término.

Answer (score 2):

Estoy de acuerdo en utilizar los términos en su idioma original, pero es muy útil pensar el significado explícito, contextual o figurativo de un término porque debería representar en nuestra mente algo equivalente a lo que percibe un individuo en el idioma de origen. Pues en el caso de la lengüeta del zapato, viene bien el término en español, "calzador", ya que es como calzar un aplicación en cualquier dispositivo (zapato), que es un objetivo central de *«bootstrap»*

Comment: Interesante reflexión...

Answer (score 2):

Como ya han comentado los demás, no hay que buscarle una traducción literal.

El concepto de hacer "Bootstrap" es básicamente dejar todo preparado para que un sistema pueda arrancar desde cero sin problemas. Puede suponer un borrado de archivos de caché, limpiado de variables, lo que haga falta para que el sistema esté listo para arrancar "limpio".

Yo internamente, y para que los nuevos lo entiendan, hacer "bootstrap", lo llamo "cebar el cañón", es decir, figurativamente el paso previo al ruidoso disparo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que en términos generales, la palabra "bootstrapping" se podría entender en español como "iniciar algo con tus propios medios o recursos".....

Comment: Probablemente el OP buscaba una palabra, no una explicacion.

Answer (score 0):

La mayoría de los términos tecnológicos técnicos suelen mantenerese en su idioma original, en este caso en inglés ya que muchas veces son siglas, metáforas o expresiones que se deben a la idiosincrasia y cultura regional por lo que cuando es traducido no tiene mucho sentido y normalmente para casos como estos en los que el público es gente que conoce de esa terminología, lo mejor es mantener la palabra o el término en su idioma original.