# ¿Existe "decrementar" en español?

Tags: palabras-raras

Lo he escuchado y leído mucho, sobre todo en entornos informáticos, pero me da la sensación de que es una mala traducción de "decrease".

¿Alguien podría confirmarlo?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pese a la creencia general, el DLE (antes DRAE) no es exhaustivo. En él no aparecen todas las palabras derivadas y, sobre todo, no aparece el vocabulario técnico o propio de un área específica.

En este caso, sí aparece la palabra *decremento* (sinónimo de *disminución*), de la que podemos derivar *decrementar* como verbo bien formado que, tal como dices, se utiliza frecuentemente en informática. Por tanto, podemos considerarlo una palabra correcta.

EDICIÓN: Como bien dice @Mauricio Martínez en su respuestas, la palabra [**decrementar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BzK2xkW) aparece ya en las últimas ediciones del DLE como derivada de *decremento* y sinónima de *disminuir*.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo tendré en cuenta. De todas formas no es sólo el DRAE, sino también María Moliner, y, aunque menos ortodoxo, WordReference. Parece que este verbo es invisible a toda la bibliografía lingüistica.

Comment: @toscanelli pero lo que dice Gorpik es que el mere hecho de no estar incluido no indica que una palabra no existe.  Es frecuente que, si por el prefijo o sufijo de una palabra (formada a base de otra palabra ya registrada) el significado de una palabra es *transparente* (evidente por sí).  Inclúyense por eso los prefijos en los diccionarios.  Es más común incluir las palabras una vez que se lexicalicen (es decir, adquirir significados opacos, como es *suponer* de *poner* que ya no significa «poner debajo»)

Comment: Buen comentario, @guifa. En efecto, los diccionarios tienden a no incluir palabras derivadas o compuestas cuando su significado es, simplemente, el que corresponde a sus elementos compositivos.

Comment: También creo que es necesario recordar que ambos verbos *[in|de]crement* en inglés se usa casi exclusivamente en el mundo informático.  (como sustantivos disfrutan de un uso mucho más amplio)

Answer (score 7):

Pues ahora ya existe:

[decrementar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BzK2xkW)

> Der. de decremento.
>   1. tr. disminuir. U. t. c. prnl.

Answer (score 2):

No es una palabra considerada dentro del diccionario de la RAE, pero yo creo que se puede utilizar y es entendible, pese a ser argot.

Coincido en que es una traducción literal de "decrease".

Un equivalente correcto podría ser [decrecer](http://dle.rae.es/decrecer), que sí está reconocida.

Saludos.

Comment: En casos de traducción, utilizo *disminuír* cuando en Inglés se utiliza *decrease*, mas sin embargo, como dices, se puede utilizar y entender, aunque exista a quien le moleste que no sea una palabra veridica dentro de los diccionarios.

Answer (score 2):

[La RAE no admite decrementar](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=decrementar).

El término anglosajón `increment` (cause a discrete increase in a numerical quantity) se usa mucho en computación. Su opuesto `decrement`, no tiene una traducción cercana al español. El problema es que `incrementar` tampoco tiene antónimos cómodos en español. Los más cercanos serían `disminuir` (si seguimos en el contexto de la computación) o `acortar`, que parecen más relacionas con `aumentar` y `alargar`, respectivamente.

`Decrementar` es otro de esos términos tomados del inglés que [no tienen una traducción cómoda en español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8492/5481). Cuando estás en un medio donde la mayoría de los términos están en inglés (bucles `while` o `for`) o puedes nombrar tranquilamente su equivalente inglés y todavía hacer que tus colegas te entiendan (waterfall, agile, extreme programming), termina por salirte un `decrementar` cuando hablas.

Comment: Creo que la duda nos la genera la existencia de `incrementar` y la inexistencia de `decrementar`, porque si no, todos usaríamos `aumentar` y `disminuir` sin ninguna comedura de cabeza. Por alguna razón, `incrementar`no tiene un antónimo directo y natural.

Comment: @toscanelli, eso y la continua exposición a los términos anglosajones en informática. Terminas forzando esas "traducciones".

Comment: _Decrementar_, como dice Gorpik, proviene de _decremento_, y no del inglés.

Comment: @Lucas, en inglés puedes forzar un nombre en un verbo y viceversa (ejemplo, googlear). No le quito razón a gorpik, pero el que exista el nombre _decremento_ no quiere decir que exista un verbo _decrementar_ y que venga de ese vocablo. Cuántas veces oyes tú que "el paro se decrementó", o que el paro o la temperatura han sufrido un decremento, o similar? El uso de decrementar, en mi opinión, viene de tratar de forzar un antónimo para _incrementar_, en la manera que se hace en inglés de convertir un nombre en un verbo.

Comment: @Diego Que no uses algo, no quiere decir que no exista, y que por influencia de otro idioma empieces a usar un verbo poco usado no lo convierte en extranjero.

Comment: @Quarkex, estoy de acuerdo, pero no es sólo que yo no lo use, es lo que cuesta encontrarlo en el diccionario de la RAE, sea exhaustivo o no, o usado en material escrito. Tampoco digo que la palabra provenga del inglés, si no que la exposición a ciertos términos a veces te lleva a hacer, como se hace en inglés, un verbo de un nombre.

Comment: De todas formas, sigue pareciéndome que igual que tenemos _incremento_ e _incrementar_, podemos formar el verbo _decrementar_ a partir de _decremento_, y no necesitamos echawrle la "culpa" a la palabra "decrease", que ni se parece a _decrementar_. Decrementar es castellano proveniente del castellano y/o del latín (decrementum), pero no del inglés.

Comment: @Lucas, te doy toda la razón, pero para que ibas a inventarte _decrementar_ teniendo ya _diminuir_? Qué es lo que te **motiva** a decir "_decrementar_"? No es que la palabra venga de _decrease_ sino que el forzar _decrementar_ a partir de _decremento_ viene de la exposición a los términos anglosajones en informática. Si no, todas las preguntas de "existe X?" se podrían resolver con "ignora a la RAE, si lo oyes existe y no pueden decirte que esté mal dicho".

Comment: @Diego, supongo que servirá para lo mismo que tenemos muchisimos otros sinónimos cuyos significados no están totalmente solapados (en este caso de merma, disminución, reducción, etc. ¿para qué queremos esas palabras si son lo mismo?). Y no, no se podrían resolver todas las preguntas "existe X?" con un "ignora a la RAE", porque todas las cosas que se dicen no siguen las reglas de formación de neologismos que tan necesarios son a menudo en las ciencias.

Answer (score 1):

`Disminuir`, `Menguar` y `Mermar` parecen buenas aproximaciones para dicha palabra.
Ciertamente, la RAE no admite `Decrementar`.